# SQL Constraint Validation without incrementing the Sequence - Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I made a SQL Constraint in a form but we when enter something wrong it give us the constraint error but the Form is still not saved, but the problem is behind,  the system make the incrementation of the sequence of this form. knowing that i make the sequence to get created only once the from get saved by super the create function.

How can make a validation of Constraint without incrementing the Sequence ?

This My Sequence Code

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get('name','/')=='/':    
       sequence = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('archive.dossier')
       vals['name'] = sequence
    return super(oeArchiveDossier, self).create(vals)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types (Implementation) of sequence used in odoo.

- Standard
- No Gap

**Standard**

If you selected this implementation type in sequence (it's default) then sequence will be created in postgresql and managed by postgresql. There is no such control over it. So in case any transactions gets failed then sequence (next number) won't rollbacked.

**No Gap**

If you select this implementation type then it will be managed by odoo, so in case any issue is there then no sequence number will be skipped.

[image]

To better control the validations there is an option in odoo to set method for constrains.

```
@api.constrains('field1', 'field2')
def check_validations(self):
      ## Perform Validation
      ## If condition not satisfied then raise an error.
      if validation_conditions:
          ## Raise an error
```